# Break doesn't work properly

Tags: php, html, break

```
foreach($item_cost as $node) {
            if($node->textContent != "$0" || $node->textContent != "$0.00" || $node->textContent != "S$0" || $node->textContent != "S$0.00" ){
                $price = $node->textContent;
                break;
            }
        }
```

I'm trying to make it Skip 0.00 and grab the first value found eg 17.50

I'm still getting 0.00

Comment: What is the exact value of `$node->textContent`?

Comment: it isn't the break what's wrong there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change your if clauses to this:

```
foreach($item_cost as $node) {
  if (!in_array($node->textContent, array("$0","$0.00","S$0","S$0.00"))) {
    $price = $node->textContent;
    break;
  }
}
```

easier to read and works better.

And if you need all prices (not just first) use it like this:

```
$prices = array();

foreach($item_cost as $node) {
  if (!in_array($node->textContent, array("$0","$0.00","S$0","S$0.00"))) {
     $prices[] = $node->textContent;
  }
}
```

now `$prices` array includes all non empty values.

Comment: Nice , thank you. Oh ya, but when i have the Break on, i get no result, if i remove it , and echo i get a few results

Comment: break; exits the whole foreach -loop but it assigns value for $price before that. So do you need to get all values that isn't empty?

Comment: I only need to get 1 Value it seems like $price = $node->textContent; the value isnt being updated in the variable. I tried $price = "asdasdasd" and it's updated

Comment: Ok, then you don't have value in $node->textContent try to figure it out.

Comment: The break kills everything, i'm not sure how it works but the array is a good solution overthis issue

Answer (score 1):

Your binary operators should be `&&` and not `||`, because `$node->textContent` must not be equal to any of the given string values.

```
if($node->textContent != "$0" && $node->textContent != "$0.00" && $node->textContent != "S$0" && $node->textContent != "S$0.00" ){
```

Alternatively, you could consider a regular expression to match against something that's worth zero dollars in either US dollars or Singapore dollars:

```
if (!preg_match('/^S?\$0(\.00)?$/', $node->textContent)) {
    $price = $node->textContent;
    break;
}
```

Or, use `in_array()` with a fixed set of values to match against.

Comment: If i put &&, does it mean that all the condition has to be met? but each text doesnt have all condition at once. they can only have one kind of condition at once?

Comment: @TransformBinary Yes, all conditions must be met, in the sense that the variable must not be equal *any* of the values.